# For Which $a$ In $[0,1]^n$ Is $\text{frac}(ta)$ Maximally Aperiodic

Tags: optimization, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

I know that there is no 'nice' solution to this question, but I'm just curious if there exists a solution at all...

Let $c$ be the $n$-cube $[0,1]^n$.

Given a vector $a\in c$, we can look at the value $A_T:=\sup_{x\in c}\inf_{t\in[0,T]}d(x,ta)$ where $d$ is the "mod" metric (I don't know the proper name) with $d(x,y):=\min_{z\in\mathbf{Z}^n}\|y-x+z\|$.

For some $a$, $A_T$ will decrease faster than for others.  For example if the $a_i$ have a common multiple, $A_T$ stops decreasing after reaching that multiple. But is there an $a$ such that $A_T$ dominates all the other $A'_T$s after some point, in the sense that there is some $T_0>0$ with $A_T\le A_T'$ for $T\ge T_0$.

Maybe $a:=(\phi^{-i})_{i<n}$ is ideal, with $\phi$ being the golden ratio?

Comment: The following phrase you wrote is not clear: *$A_T$ dominates all the other $A'_T$s after some point*.  I'm not even sure I can guess what you mean by that. Can you restate that as an actual mathematical sentence, with correct quantifiers and so on?

Comment: Ah sorry, will make an edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples as you have asked for can be constructed using dimensional considerations.

Let's suppose for instance that we are in dimension $n=3$, and that the vector $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is limited to dimension $2$ by selecting $a_3=0$:
$$a = (a_1,a_2,0)
$$
If $x = (0,0,.1)$ then it follows that $A_T = .1$ for all $T \ge 0$. More generally, if $x = (K a_1, K a_2, .1)$ then for all $T \ge K$ we have $A_T = .1$.

What can occur more generally in dimension $n=3$ is that there exist integers $P,Q,R$ such that $(P,Q,R) \cdot (a_1,a_2,a_3) = Pa_1 + Q a_2 + Ra_3 = 0$. In this situation, consider the set $S$ that is obtained by taking the union of the plane $Px+Qy+Rz=0$ with all of its translates under the action of $\mathbb Z^3$. The individual planes comprising the set $S$ are separated from each other by a positive distance, i.e. $S$ is *not* a dense subset of $\mathbb R^3$. Suppose we choose a number $\epsilon$ which is less than half that distance. Suppose also that we take the point $x$ so that the vector from $(0,0,0)$ to $x$ points in the same direction as the vector $\langle P,Q,R \rangle$ and has length equal to $\epsilon$:
$$x = \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{P^2 + Q^2 + R^2}} \bigl(P,Q,R\bigr)
$$
In this case again it follows that $A_T = \epsilon$ for all $T \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'm not sure if I understand correctly, you write if $x=\dots$ then $A_t=\dots$ but my $A_t$ does not depend on $x$, the $x$ is bound by the $\sup$!  Do I overlook something?

Comment: I'm basically asking, how can we choose $a$ such that $\text{frac}(ta)$ covers the cube as dense as possible.

Comment: Ah, yes, I miswrote my answer somewhat. I don't have time to fix it at the moment, but very briefly: I should have chosen $x=(0,0,.5)$ in my first example, which gives $A_T=.5$; and I should have chosen $\epsilon$ to be half the distance in the second example, which gives $A_T$ equal to *that* choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Well, actually, you asked how we can choose $a$ so that frac(ta) does NOT cover the cube as densely as possible, and that's how I wrote my answer (miswriting aside).

Comment: Ah sorry, I had a typo for a short time after I edited the question, where I had $A'_T\le A_T$, was that the confusion?

Comment: I mean, if you want $A_T'\le A_T$, isn't that trivial by choosing $a=0$?  But again, please tell me if you read the current version of the question or something with a temporary typo, in the latter case I'll of course accept your answer because I made the mistake!